# Different IP Addresses from the same machine

Tags: java, networking, dns

I have a client-server setup. Where client connects to the server and asks which program to execute next. Server after getting a request checks for the hostname of the other end of the socket using below chunk of code which returns "127.0.0.1"

```
socket.getInetAddress().getCanonicalHostName();
```

After getting the program name the client creates a process which also tries to connect to the server but this time the above call returns different address. "mypc.foo.com" ***masking the domain name here***

This behavior is bugging me as I am unable to lookup the `hashmap` where I store all the process details grouped by the machine ip.

Is it a bug in java lookup implementation or am I missing something. Please suggest some other way to do this lookup

Answer (score 1):

I beleive socket.getInetAddress() returns your own address so basically always 127.0.0.1. Try using socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() - to get the other party's ip address.

Using IP address to match distinct users is generally a bad idea though. First of all they can be in some network or behind firewall and you can get requests from multiple clients coming from the same IP address. Also you are not guaranteed that it is static or dynamic IP. And also if your application is running in some strange network setup with strange routing you might end up getting all requests from the router IP address.

The better design would be to share some token between the server and the client and use that for identification. Does it sound familiar? For example http sessions are done like that ;)

Comment: Yeah! I thought of it.. But we can also spoof it right?

Comment: @MadhusoodanP So you are worried that a client spoofs his token, but not worried about IP address manipulations? If so, that doesn't really fit together.

Comment: But it adds an additional complexity of managing the tokens and however the server also sometime connects back to the client to kill the process (Yes the client who connected first also listens on a port :P). So I believe going with IP address is better way. (Please correct me)

Comment: It is alright but it adds some dependency on the infrastructure. Imagine you have a local network with 5 machines connected to the internet from the same router. Your server is remotely located in the internet. All these machines will show you either their router/shared IP address or their local network address and in both cases it won't work for you. Also if you have some hardware firewall or load balancer or badly setup router or whatever in your network you will always get their IP. It won't be much better in that cases with tokens if you need to connect back though

Comment: Ok let me go for one more level of abstraction

Comment: @VeselinDavidov Even after using the getRemoteSocketAddress() it returns different IPs.

Comment: damn I was wrong then. I guess it is probably the second scenario and something is masking the IP